# menu items saved with menu_link_save() don't have the delete button, and I can't edit the menu path

Tags: routes

When I add menu items manually, they work fine.  When I try this I get no delete link in the admin, and I can't edit the menu items.

```
$link = array();
$link['link_title'] = "text";
$link['link_path'] = 'node';
$link['menu_name'] = $menu;
$link['expanded'] = 1;
$link['module'] = "dl_migration";
$link['weight'] = $i;
menu_link_save( $link );
menu_cache_clear_all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the module name is what caused the lack of ability to delete.  I'm not sure why, though.  Sort of lame I think.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the "delete" link is not shown is that the link is only shown when the menu item is created by (or associated to) the Menu module. [_menu_overview_tree_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.admin.inc/function/_menu_overview_tree_form/6) contains the following code:

```
  // Only items created by the menu module can be deleted.
  if ($item['module'] == 'menu' || $item['updated'] == 1) {
    $operations['delete'] = l(t('delete'), 'admin/build/menu/item/' . $item['mlid'] . '/delete');
  }
```

[menu_link_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_link_save/7) uses some defaults for the array `$item` passed as argument; this means that if the module associated with the menu link is not explicitly set, it receives the default value ("menu").

```
  // Load defaults.
  $item += array(
    'menu_name' => 'navigation', 
    'weight' => 0, 
    'link_title' => '', 
    'hidden' => 0, 
    'has_children' => 0, 
    'expanded' => 0, 
    'options' => array(), 
    'module' => 'menu', 
    'customized' => 0, 
    'updated' => 0,
  );
```

Comment: Uhm, yeah, that's what I said above.  Thanks for fleshing out the answer tho.  It's a stupid paradigm though, don'tcha think?

Comment: I think the idea is that users should not be allowed to delete links programmatically added by third-party modules; users should just be able to disable those links. It makes perfectly sense to me, especially in the case a module help text makes reference to those links.

Comment: It should be an option -- during the large migration I'm setting up we are going to be using a module to create a set of menus.  Marking those with our module name is preferable because it limits things conceptually.  Ah well.

Comment: You can propose a feature request for Drupal. It would help to have a flag that allows to modules to create a menu link that can be deleted from users, even if the value for "module" is not "menu." In that way, a module could add custom links users can delete, and still be able to delete the links when it is uninstalled.